# Managing instances of programmatically instantiated view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

If I instantiate a ViewController from my storyboard programatically, will its memory be freed once it's no longer be shown in the application?

I'm showing it as a modal.

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on @Schemetrical's answer, you need to make sure there is at least one strong reference to your VC or it will be deallocated immediately.

This is a crash in the making:

```
func viewDidLoad()
{
  childVC = self.storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("childVC")
  self.view.addSubview(childVC.view)
}
```

In the above example the current VC's content view keeps ownership of the newly created view, but nobody keeps ownership of the view controller. It gets deallocated as soon as the function returns, and the first time something tries to reference the now-deallocated VC, you crash (Say there is a button who's action points to the VC.)

If you push your VC onto the navigation stack, the navigation controller takes ownership. As soon as it's popped off the stack, it gets deallocated. If you present your VC modally, the system takes ownership for as long as it's on screen. As soon as it'd dismissed it gets deallocated.

If you want a VC to stick around after it's popped/dismissed, you need to keep a strong reference to it somewhere. You might save a reference to it in your app delegate, in a singleton, or in your app's root view controller.

Comment: Additionally, since you're presenting it in a modal, `-presentViewController:animated:` will hold on to the destination view controller until you call `-dismissViewController:animated:`.

Comment: @Schemetrical, I covered that case in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as nothing holds strongly on the vc, it will dealloc. Once you dismiss that vc, the view releases its reference on the object and since there are no references, it will dealloc.